# AWS cli getting the InstanceStatus or SystemStatus reachability status as single string without using jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, aws-cli, status

I try to find a way to get the instance InstanceStatus and reachability status without using jq (not installed )
the closes i found is :

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-066fxxxxx --filters Name=instance-status.reachability,Values=passed
```

which gives me if it passed :

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-066fxxxxx",
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And empty when it is not passed like this:

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": []
}
```

I like to get only the value of the status of InstanceStatus or SystemStatus ( one time i will call to get InstanceStatus and the other to get info about SystemStatus )

i need to get just the value :
"passed" or any other status

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $INSTANCEID --query 'InstanceStatuses[].InstanceStatus[].Status' --output=text
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).